# Stm32 freertos, all variable can not be change in my project

Tags: variables, extern, stm32

I don't understand why freertos do not allow to change extern variables
(myData)
here is my poject

---

file main.c

```
uint16_t Mydata = 0;

main()
{
    System_Init();
    xTaskCreate(Task1, (const char*)"Task1", 100, NULL, 4, NULL);   
    xTaskCreate(Task2, (const char*)"Task2", 100, NULL, 3, NULL);   
    vTaskStartScheduler();
}
```

---

file Task1.c

```
extern uint16_t Mydata;

void Task1(void *p)
{ 
    while(1)
    {
        vTaskDelay(10);
        printf("Result: %d", Mydata);
    }
}
```

---

file Task2.c

```
extern uint16_t Mydata;

void Task2(void *p)
{
    while(1)
    {
       Mydata++;
       vTaskDelay(10);
    }
}
```

---

but the result is never correct

most of result is like "13842930", "-18234952", or something like that !

can anyone tell me why?
(I'm sorry because of my bad English)
thank for your help !

Answer (score 2):

1. You cannot use `%d` for printing a value of `uint16_t`. `%d` expects an `int`. You either have to cast your value to `int` in the `printf()` call (`printf("Result: %d", (int)Mydata);`), or use proper specifier (`printf("Result: %" PRIu16 "", Mydata);`). The second solution might not be supported by your toolchain.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf

2. Your variable should be declared `volatile`, otherwise compiler may as well read it once an never update the value from RAM.

Comment: Thank you so much !

Comment: i 've changed my project like what you tell me to do but the error doesn't disappear. Do i need any funtion to transer data from one Task to another task?

Comment: @loi.efy - the problem must be elsewhere. I suspect that you may overwrite global variables due to stack overflow in your thread. Depending on exact compilation flags and toolchain configuration, `printf()` can use up to 2kB of stack (yes - that's correct - two kilobytes). You provide only 100B to your thread which is far too little for anything useful. I'd then start by drastically increasing stack size (3-4kB for the thread with `printf()`) and enabling stack overflow checks.